# What does this := operator in VB means?

Tags: .net, vb.net

It was used in `<RequireAuthorization(Permission:="Manage Users")>`. I know its an assignment operator but whats the difference with it from the '=' ?

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302486/what-is-the-operator-in-vb-net-or-what-is-it-good-for?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a *named argument* (as separate to the default conventional of *positional* arguments):

- it makes it easy for the reader to see that that value represents
- it makes it easy for the writer to supply a value to the 17th optional parameter without needing to specify all the others (or include lots of commas, etc)

Answer (score 1):

It's used to pass values for named parameters to a method, in this case the constructor of the `RequireAuthorizationAttribute`.